# Apply function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function for geo-location that I want to apply to different pandas dataframes that I get by using some other functions.
I want to do something like this, but i do not know how:

```
deadly.apply(geolocation())
```

This is the code for reading pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

names = ["ID", "Vreme", "E", "N", "Ishod", "Tip", "Opis"]
my_dataFrame = pd.read_csv("SaobracajBeograd.csv",  header = None, names = names)
```

This is the function that I want to apply:

```
def geolocation():

    #extract only coordinates and convert them to tuple
    coordinates_data = my_dataFrame[["N", "E"]]
    coordinates_data = coordinates_data.apply(tuple, axis=1)

    #add tuple coordinates to list
    coordinate_list = []
    for coord in coordinates_data:
        coordinate_list.append(coord)

    #defult map location
    gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(44.797140, 20.513460, 11)

    # Scatter points
    coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons = zip(*coordinate_list)
    gmap.scatter(coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, 'red', size = 150, marker = False)

    # Draw
    gmap.draw("my_map1.html")

#geolocation()
```

And this is the function that gives me dataframe witch I want to use for applying the function, and result of that function:

```
def accidents_with_deadly_outcome():

    deadly = my_dataFrame[my_dataFrame["Ishod"] == "Sa poginulim"]
    deadly = deadly[["Ishod", "E", "N"]].reset_index(drop=True)
    return deadly

#print(accidents_with_deadly_outcome())
```

Result of `accidents_with_deadly_outcome():` function:

```
0  Sa poginulim  20.657460  44.490140
1  Sa poginulim  20.654150  44.468720
2  Sa poginulim  20.536690  44.787231
3  Sa poginulim  20.510760  44.652443
4  Sa poginulim  20.510540  44.884460
5  Sa poginulim  20.471758  44.788613
6  Sa poginulim  20.359841  44.742405
7  Sa poginulim  20.472120  44.763520
8  Sa poginulim  20.610525  44.676290
```

Comment: You've got a bit of work to do to get to an [mcve] so that the problem can be better articulated.  Couple things: Provide sample data and expected outputs. Separate the concerns of processing the dataframe and visualizing its data.  `pandas.apply()` is most effective for transforming your geospatial data which can then be passed to something that displays it. If you can exclude the display parts which are impossible to recreate, you will get better responses.

Comment: `apply` needs function's name without `()` - it is offen called `"callback"` - `deadly.apply(geolocation)`

Comment: @RichAndrews I have changed my code a lil bit. I just do not know what should my `def geolocation():` function return so that i can use it later.

Comment: You do not want to use `apply` with that `geolocation` function. You only need to pass the dataframe as a parameter to the function (and pass the `deadly` dataframe instead of the `my_dataFrame` one)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Can you  please write me an example code?